# Why does lifting the resultant array make the recursion work as expected?

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

Consider the following tree.

[image: Example Tree]

It's represented by the following data structure.

```js
const Node = (name, value, children) => ({ name, value, children });

const tree = Node("A", 4, [
    Node("B", 7, [
        Node("C", 9, [])
    ]),
    Node("D", 11, [
        Node("E", 9, [])
    ]),
    Node("F", 55, []),
    Node("G", 65, [
        Node("H", 21, []),
        Node("I", 23, [])
    ])
]);
```

Now, I want to get an array of all the values in the tree greater than a certain value. Here's what I tried.

```js
const Node = (name, value, children) => ({ name, value, children });

const tree = Node("A", 4, [
    Node("B", 7, [
        Node("C", 9, [])
    ]),
    Node("D", 11, [
        Node("E", 9, [])
    ]),
    Node("F", 55, []),
    Node("G", 65, [
        Node("H", 21, []),
        Node("I", 23, [])
    ])
]);

const result = findHigherInNode(tree, 20);

console.log(result);

function findHigherInNode(node, num) {
    console.log(node.name);
    const isGreater = [];
    if (node.value > num) {
        isGreater.push(node.value);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
        findHigherInNode(node.children[i], num);
    }
    return isGreater;
}
```

Note that although I'm traversing the entire tree, yet I'm not getting the correct result.

However, if I move the recursion into a local `recurse` function while keeping the `isGreater` array in the same scope then it works.

```js
const Node = (name, value, children) => ({ name, value, children });

const tree = Node("A", 4, [
    Node("B", 7, [
        Node("C", 9, [])
    ]),
    Node("D", 11, [
        Node("E", 9, [])
    ]),
    Node("F", 55, []),
    Node("G", 65, [
        Node("H", 21, []),
        Node("I", 23, [])
    ])
]);

const result = findHigherInNode(tree, 20);

console.log(result);

function findHigherInNode(node, num) {
    const isGreater = [];
    function recurse(node, num) {
        if (node.value > num) {
            isGreater.push(node.value);
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            recurse(node.children[i], num);
        }
    }
    recurse(node, num);
    return isGreater;
}
```

Why does my first code snippet produce the wrong result? Why does my second code snippet produce the right result? The only difference between them is that the `isGreater` array is lifted to a higher scope in the second code snippet.

Comment: The first version redefines a totally new array on every call and the second version uses one for the entire recursive process. The second version has a typo: `sum` should probably be `isGreater`. Secondly, there's a hardcoded 20 that should probably be `num` (`num` is a knob you're giving to the caller so your function doesn't just work on 20 only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why does my first code snippet produce the wrong result?**

Because `isGreater` is a new binding, initialized to `[]` each time `findHigherInNode` is called

**Why does my second code snippet produce the right result?**

Because `isGreater` is initialized once after `findHigherInNode` is called, and `recurse` does not create a new binding for each subsequent call

**Why am I experiencing this kind of problem?**

Because you are not using generators! Generators make this kind of problem disappear -

```js
function* inorder (t)
{ yield t.value
  for (const c of t.children)
    yield *inorder(c)
}

const tree =
  {name: 'A',value: 21,children: [{name: 'B', value: 7,children: [{name: 'C', value: 9, children: []}]},{name: 'D', value: 11,children: [{name: 'E', value: 9, children: []}]},{name: 'F', value: 55, children: []},{name: 'G', value: 65,children: [{name: 'H', value: 21, children: []},{name: 'I', value: 33, children: []}]}]}
  
for (const v of inorder(tree))
  if (v > 20)
    console.log(v)
```

```
21
55
65
21
33
```

However, it would probably be smarter to yield the entire node, allowing the caller of the generator to choose which data is relevant to select from the traversal

```js
function* inorder (t)
{ yield t                       // <- yield entire node
  for (const c of t.children)
    yield *inorder(c)
}

const tree =
  {name: 'A',value: 21,children: [{name: 'B', value: 7,children: [{name: 'C', value: 9, children: []}]},{name: 'D', value: 11,children: [{name: 'E', value: 9, children: []}]},{name: 'F', value: 55, children: []},{name: 'G', value: 65,children: [{name: 'H', value: 21, children: []},{name: 'I', value: 33, children: []}]}]}

for (const node of inorder(tree))
  if (node.value > 20)                    // <- entire node accessible here
    console.log(node.name, node.value)
```

```
A 21
F 55
G 65
H 21
I 33
```

**But is it possible without generators?**

Yep.

```js
function inorder (t)
{
  return [t, ...t.children.flatMap(inorder)]
}

const tree =
  {name: 'A',value: 21,children: [{name: 'B', value: 7,children: [{name: 'C', value: 9, children: []}]},{name: 'D', value: 11,children: [{name: 'E', value: 9, children: []}]},{name: 'F', value: 55, children: []},{name: 'G', value: 65,children: [{name: 'H', value: 21, children: []},{name: 'I', value: 33, children: []}]}]}
  
for (const node of inorder(tree))
  if (node.value > 20)
    console.log(node.name, node.value)
```

```
A 21
F 55
G 65
H 21
I 33
```

Comment: Although this is a nice solution, yet it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Disclaimer: I edited the OP's question, but I don't think I changed the gist of the question.

Comment: Thanks for calling me out Aadit. I made an edit. I hope you are well :D

Comment: I don't know if you meant an alternate meaning for "inorder", but this is not an inorder traversal, it's "preorder".  Preorder is `root -> children`.  Postorder is `children -> root`.  Inorder is only defined for binary trees and it's `left child -> root -> right child`.